# sorting the table when user click on the column

Tags: javascript, html

I have the html table which populated the dynamic values from json(written in the javascript code).
When user click on any column header in the table, the table should sort accordingly. Any suggestions would be helpful.

When user click on the column the table should sort ascending and then descending if user clicks for the second time on the same column.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/o2ram4tu/

Sample code below:

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "3",
                "Book Name": "Popular Science",
                "Category": "Science",
                "Price": "210.40"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.getElementById("resulttable");
 var tr = table.insertRow(1);   

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
    <style>
        th, td, p, input {
            font:14px Verdana;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="CreateTableFromJSON()" > 
<table class="fdt-datatable" id="resulttable" name="resulttable">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th name = "bookID"> Book ID</th>
                <th name = "bookName"> Book Name</th>
                <th name = "category"> Category</th>
                <th name = "price"> Price</th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
    <p id="showData"></p>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Datatable is best for this type of functionality.

Comment: why you dont use a third party component for this?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any click listeners. Does it make sense for you to sort on the client?

Comment: You can:
1. Move myBooks into a higher closure
2. Reorder myBooks when the user click on the header
3. Destroy old data in your HTML table
4. recreate your HTML table from the reordered myBooks
This is not optimal, but this is the simplest answer I can think.

Comment: The naming of your object keys seems to be bad , use underscores or lowerCamelCase to name the keys so that you can access them in your sort function. Add onClick listener to the headers , pass the key you want to sort with , sort the object and re create your table !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question from coment about this [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/scb6axLh/)

**HTML part**
You have table with everything in `tbody`. I separated row with `th` to `thead` and I have empty `tbody`. Because I need to separate header fields which is clickable, and to separate content which can be sort.
Important thing is to add class `sortable` on which column you want to be sortable. In this case all column is sortable except first with checkboxes

**JavaScript part**
I added `var tbody = document.getElementById("resulttable_body");` and at the end all rows are added to our empty `tbody.appendChild(row);`
Mayor thing is that you created element `input` and you append input to table cell, which look like this image:

[image]

I've created **td** element and put **input** inside it

```
    //Multi Stage Checkbox creation
    tblCell = document.createElement('td');
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    input.setAttribute("name", "");
    input.setAttribute("value", "");
    input.setAttribute("id", 1);
    tblCell.appendChild(input);
    tblCell.style.textAlign = 'center';
    row.appendChild(tblCell);
```

Answer (score 4):

I edited your code and add some new staff fort sortering
Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozabh9gv/)
Snippet is below

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "3",
                "Book Name": "Popular Science",
                "Category": "Science",
                "Price": "210.40"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.getElementById("resulttable");
        var tbody = document.getElementById("resulttable_body");
        var tr = tbody.insertRow(0);   

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = tbody.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }

 
// FOR TABLE SORT
$(document).ready(function(){

var sortOrder = 1; // flag to toggle the sorting order
function getVal(elm, colIndex){
 var td = $(elm).children('td').eq(colIndex).text();
 if(typeof td !== "undefined"){
  var v = td.toUpperCase();
  if($.isNumeric(v)){
   v = parseInt(v,10);
  }
  return v;
 }
}

$(document).on('click', '.sortable', function(){
 var self = $(this);
 var colIndex = self.prevAll().length;
 var o = (sortOrder == 1) ? 'asc' : 'desc'; // you can use for css to show sort direction
 sortOrder *= -1; // toggle the sorting order
 
    $('.sortable').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
    self.addClass(o);

 var tbody = self.closest("table").find("tbody");
 var tr = tbody.children("tr"); //.get();

    tr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a, colIndex);
        var B = getVal(b, colIndex);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*sortOrder;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*sortOrder;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    $.each(tr, function(index, row) {
  //console.dir(row)
        tbody.append(row);
    });

});

});
```

```css
        th, td, p, input {
            font:14px Verdana;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
</head>
<body onload="CreateTableFromJSON()" > 
<table class="fdt-datatable" id="resulttable" name="resulttable">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th name = "bookID" class="sortable"> Book ID</th>
 <th name = "bookName" class="sortable"> Book Name</th>
 <th name = "category" class="sortable"> Category</th>
 <th name = "price" class="sortable"> Price</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="resulttable_body">
</tbody>
</table>
<p id="showData"></p>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to implement as you suggested, but it is not working in my sample code shown in the link https://jsfiddle.net/scb6axLh/ . Any inputs would be helpful.Thanks @Nebojsa Nebojsa

Comment: Now it is sortable when clicking on `th` https://jsfiddle.net/62n9vhta/ I will explain in the new post what I have corrected